# Relational DB concept for targeting of product offers

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema, recommendation-engine

I got assigned a task to develop system for product offering based on target groups. Groups are defined mainly by gender, age and a type(s) of already purchased product(s). I would like to make DB concept as robust as possible to allow future improvements of targeting.

I am sure this might be considered a high valued know-how, nevertheless are there any general solutions to this or resources to start with?

Comment: Google "Recommender Systems". There is a large body of research and practice and there are plenty of books on the topic.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know how is that called so you can consider your comment an answer.